# visual studio and c

Tags: c, visual-studio

i'm practicing c and looking to use visual studio. but can I write console C programs and debug it step by step? (i use debug for understading algorithms step by step)

thank you.

Comment: Surely this could have been googled.

Comment: If your C++ compiler works as specified by the Standard, you can check the preprocessor symbol `__cplusplus` and make sure you're compiling as C. `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error Please do not use a C++ compiler` / `#endif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Start off with the c++ version (if you are using Express), it supports c as well.

Visual Studio has a very good debugger and will allow you to step through your code.

Comment: as i only need c support. should i install visual c++ express?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. The others will not have c support.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple press f9 at a line of interest to create a breakpoint.

Press F5 and the debug will stop at the breakpoint. From there uses F10 and/or F11 to step the code.

Also pressing F10 will start the debug at the first line of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can code in C++ in Visual Studio, I cannot assure you you will be able to code anything (although in theory you should be able to). But if algorithms are somewhat basic C sintaxis should run well on a C++ project and you can debug such project :).

Check the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) on how to debug using breakpoints and tracepoints.